# Run SQL file with inset Commands in Java

Tags: java, netbeans, xampp

I want to run an SQL file that has a lot of Insert Statments, and I am trying to run the file, So far i found this code but its not that good as it gives me an error that the table is not found, can you have a look at the code maybe you can find the problem ?

```
      private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                    {                                         
    try {                                         

        URL = jTextField1.getText();
        username = jTextField3.getText();
        password = jTextField2.getText();

        String s = new String();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        try {
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "DELETE FROM player;";
            st.executeUpdate(query);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Delete Compleated");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        }


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
        try {

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("player.sql"));
            // be sure to not have line starting with "--" or "/*" or any other non aplhabetical character  

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(s);
            }
            br.close();

            // here is our splitter ! We use ";" as a delimiter for each request  
            // then we are sure to have well formed statements  
            String[] inst = sb.toString().split(";");


            Statement st = conn.createStatement();

            for (int i = 0; i < inst.length; i++) {
                // we ensure that there is no spaces before or after the request string  
                // in order to not execute empty statements  
                if (!inst[i].trim().equals("")) {
                    st.executeUpdate(inst[i]);
                    System.out.println(">>" + inst[i]);
                }
            }

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Loaded Compleat");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        }

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        try {

            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "Select * from player;";
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()) {
                int d1 = rs.getInt(1);
                String d2 = rs.getString("PlayerName");
                String d3 = rs.getString("PlayerSurname");
                String d4 = rs.getString("PlayingPosition");
                double d5 = rs.getDouble("PlayerRating");

                model.addRow(new Object[]{
                            d1, d2, d3, d4, d5
                        });
            }

            rs.close();
            st.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
        }

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Football.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Football.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ex);
    }

}
```

thx for any help you can give :) i am using Xampp and the database is all ready created all i need is to populate it,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you have to append new line `"\n"` in this code

```
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(s);
                sb.append("\n");
            }
```

because you append each line right after the before line